# List of users in form

Tags: component, form-fields-types

In a component, if I want to add an user field to the form, I can easily use a field of type `user`, and play with it as I want.

But what can I do if I need a field that stores an array of users?

The idea is, in the backend, to be able to add one or more objects of type `user` to that field *(let's call it, for example, `collaborators`)*, and in the frontend to be able to manipulate and show the list of users selected for that field *(in the collaborators example, it could be something like **Collaborators:** Sophia Smith, Emma Williams, Oliver Lee.)*.

**Edit:** same question extended to an array of objects of type contact, url, etc...

Comment: Perhaps use subform fields and each subform field can contain a user field?

Comment: @Lodder I'm giving a try to the subform option. But it's the first time I use multiple attribute, and I'm having hard time finding out the way to store the value in the database. Any advice on that?

Comment: I've never used subforms before. I use the old repeatable form fields still as it's the only one I like. So sorry, I cant help you on that

Comment: @Lodder Came out pretty straightforward using multiple attribute, once I've accepted to save string and not a real relationship. =D
Do you have any suggestion on what to do in order to use objects of type `contact` of instead of using objects of type `user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` type field doesn't support `multiple` attribute. I can think of 3 options:

1. Create a custom field type with `multiple` support. You can use `Author` field as example. Just change the query to be a simple select from `#__users` table https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e6d61160eff61d749328e86c01c98fc5239a198a/libraries/src/Form/Field/AuthorField.php.
2. Use SQL field. See documentation here https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type.
3. Use `Subform` field type and include `User` type field in it. https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type